# Quasar2 Vue3 Cypress slide toggle status mismatch with what is shown on Cypress browser

Tags: cypress, vuejs3, slidetoggle, quasar-framework

My vue template:

```
<template>
  <q-item tag="label" v-ripple>
    <q-item-section>
      <q-item-label class="text-mono">
        {{ name }}
      </q-item-label>
      <q-item-label caption>{{ description }}</q-item-label>
      <q-item-label
        caption
        class="text-red"
        v-show="warning"
        :key="warning"
        v-for="warning in warnings"
      >
        {{ warning }}
      </q-item-label>
      <q-item-label caption class="text-red" v-show="warningMsg">
        {{ warningMsg }}
      </q-item-label>
    </q-item-section>
    <q-item-section avatar>
      <q-toggle
        color="indigo"
        v-model="model"
        :disable="isToggleDisabled"
        @triggerFunc="btnToggleTrigger"
      />
    </q-item-section>
  </q-item>
</template>
```

I have the following cypress E2E test code snippet:

```
  it('Verify Toggle Button from auto-generated page', () => {
    cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').should("not.be.checked");
    cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').click();
    cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').should("be.checked"); // XXX
  });
```

The status validation fails AFTER the `click()`. However, cypress browser UI shows that the slider button is clicked. The error message:

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<label.q-item.q-item-type.row.no-wrap.q-item--clickable.q-link.cursor-pointer.q-focusable.q-hoverable>' to be 'checked'
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the checked element.

Comment: I am using Quasar 2 Vue 3 `q-toggle`. Not native HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<input>` is within the element that has the `data-test` attribute.

You can verify the state by one of the inner element's class.
Does not seem ideal to me, but it works.

```js
cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]')
  .find('.q-toggle__inner')
  .should('have.class', 'q-toggle__inner--falsy')

cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]')
  .find('input')
  .check({force: true});

cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]')
  .find('.q-toggle__inner')
  .should('have.class', 'q-toggle__inner--truthy')
```

Ideally, you would check the value of the `v-model` variable.

Comment: `Timed out retrying after 4050ms: cy.check() failed because this element is not visible:

<input class="hidden q-toggle__native absolute q-ma-none q-pa-none" type="checkbox">

This element <input.hidden.q-toggle__native.absolute.q-ma-none.q-pa-none> is not visible because it has CSS property: display: none`

Comment: Yes, have to use teh `force: true`. However, thesecond `should` fails: `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<input.hidden.q-toggle__native.absolute.q-ma-none.q-pa-none>' to have attribute 'aria-checked'`

Comment: Don't use aria-checked, the input element should be checked.

Comment: Tried but to no avail.

Comment: `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<input.hidden.q-toggle__native.absolute.q-ma-none.q-pa-none>' to be 'checked'`

Comment: Yeah those quasar controls behave quite strangely.

Comment: I have included the vue template in my post.

Comment: I think I missed your solution yesterday. It works but the way it works is very cryptic and not intuitive compared to a simple `should('be.checked')`.

Comment: How to check the `v-model` or any `props` value for that sake.

Comment: I was going to check that next step - in principle you add a reference to the `v-model` variable to `window` and in the test can check it's value. But I'm wondering about Vue refs, how they would work in a Cypress test.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the value of `aria-checked` is changing for the toggle. So you can so like this:

```js
//For toggle off
cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').should(
  'have.attr',
  'aria-checked',
  'false'
)

//For toggle on
cy.get('[data-test="toggle-setting-0"]').should(
  'have.attr',
  'aria-checked',
  'true'
)
```

Comment: `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<label.q-item.q-item-type.row.no-wrap.q-item--clickable.q-link.cursor-pointer.q-focusable.q-hoverable>' to have attribute 'aria-checked'`

Comment: Can you tell me which one matches yours from here - https://quasar.dev/vue-components/toggle

Comment: https://quasar.dev/vue-components/toggle

Comment: You have to point to me to the exact one.

Comment: https://quasar.dev/vue-components/toggle#qtoggle-api

Comment: I can see the `aria-checked` attribute. You have to select different locators.

Comment: I have included the vue template in my post.