# Quasar2 Vue3 Cypress select options

Tags: drop-down-menu, cypress, vuejs3, quasar-framework, optionmenu

I would like to perform the following tests with Cypruss E2E:
(1) Verify the number and content of the `select` options
(2) Select one of them and verify the value matches the selection.

This is what I have done for (2):

```
it('Verify Options from auto-generated page', () => {
    cy.get('[data-test="dropdown-setting-3"]').find('label').select("Option 1"); // OK
    cy.get('[data-test="dropdown-setting-3"]').should('have.value', 1); // XXX
});
```

I am able to select one of the options from the `q-select`.However, validation of the `value` selected fails:

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<label.q-item.q-item-type.row.no-wrap.q-item--clickable.q-link.cursor-pointer.q-focusable.q-hoverable>' to have value '1', but the value was ''
```

But none of them succeed. I have not figured out how to achieve (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quasar select has an input, but it's value does not get updated.

Instead you can check the child element span that displays the selected value.

```js
cy.get('[data-test="dropdown-setting-3"]')
  .click()                                    // open select

cy.get('.q-menu .q-item')                     // list of options
  .should('have.length', 5)                   // substitute your list count

cy.get('.q-menu .q-item')
  .click()                                    // select 2nd item

// OR
// cy.contains('Option 2')
//   .click()                                  // select 2nd item

cy.get('[data-test="dropdown-setting-3"]')
  .find('span')                               // value is displayed via span
  .should('have.text', 'Option 2')            // verify the text
```

I think the problem with using `.q-item` selector is you have an additional `<q-item>` around the `<q-select>`, but I can't see what it's purpose is.

You can strengthen the option selector by adding `.q-menu` to it (see above).

Comment: `cy.get('.q-item').should('have.length', 3)` error: `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Too many elements found. Found '14', expected '3'.`

Comment: It looks like you have multiple selects using the same data-test attribute.

Comment: No, the `data-test` attribute is unique. There is currently only ONE dropdown select control on the UI page.

Comment: `cy.get().eq(0).click({force: true});` doesn't work.

Comment: That's bad luck, it works ok on my quasar select.

Comment: That line doesn't have error but it doesn't conclude the action. The dropdown is activated to show the optinos but no option was clicked after that. See my OP for the image.

Comment: Let me compare that to my app...

Comment: Nope, it's fine for me. I presume when you put `cy.get()` in comment above, that's just lazy typing - you do have a selector in the test, right?

Comment: `[data-test="dropdown-setting-3"]'` is the selector

Comment: Yeah - you used the wrong selector. You need `.q-item` not `[data-test="dropdown-setting-3"]`.

Comment: At least that's what I used for the successful select. `[data-test="dropdown-setting-3"]` is not one of the options, it's the select control.

Comment: How to use both of them together? `control` > `q-item`

Comment: I tried `.q-item` but to no avail.

Comment: Bad luck - maybe it's something to do with the autogenerate. You will have to track down the options in the HTML.

Comment: Since you don't know the right selector for the option, why don't you try targeting it by text content -  `cy.contains('Option 1').click()`. That also works on my app.

Comment: Following the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73205100/quasar2-vue3-cypress-slide-toggle-status-mismatch-with-what-is-shown-on-cypress#73205214 how to use the same `q-<foo>__inner` for this dropdown select control?

Comment: I made a change to the selector - now it's `.q-menu .q-item` to avoid the extra `.q-item` your app uses. So this will only pick up q-item inside a menu, and the menu only appears after the dropdown is clicked open.

Comment: The only thing that works now is `cy.get('[data-test="dropdown-setting-3"]').find('label').select("Option 1");`. The string "Option 1" shows up in the dropdown box now.

Comment: `cy.get('[data-test="dropdown-setting-3"]').find('span').should('have.text', 'Option 1');` works BUT that's not the point. It should test / validate the `value` associated with the clicked `text`.

Comment: It should validate that the text changes - test it before select, should be one thing, then select and test it has changed. Yes I agree the value set in Vue is the best test, but it's difficult in e2e test. Should be easier with Component test.

Comment: You are right. Cannot validate model `value` without being bound to any UI element.

Comment: If I put a `cy.get('body').click()` in between 2 clicks, the test fails. The `span` shows the previous text. Bizarre.

Comment: Theoretically that should close the select, so it would not be possible to click an option, and the original text remains in place. But I would expect a complaint about the option click if the menu had closed.