# Quasar2 Vue3 Cypress multi-select test fails with strange error

Tags: drop-down-menu, cypress, vuejs3, html-select, quasar-framework

My template:

```
<template>
  <q-item tag="label" v-ripple>
    <q-select
      borderless
      stack-label
      emit-value
      map-options
      multiple
      class="full-width"
      v-model="model"
      :options="options"
      :label="name"
    >
      <template v-slot:after>
        <q-btn
          data-test="btnMultipleDropDownSetting"
          round
          dense
          flat
          color="primary"
          icon="done"
          @click="multiSelectionCompletes"
          :disable="submitButtonDisable"
        />
      </template>
    </q-select>
  </q-item>
</template>
```

Test code:

```
   it('Verify Multiple-Select from auto-generated page', () => {
    cy.get('[data-test="multidropdown-setting-4"]').find('label').should('contain', "Auto Generated Multi-Selection box");
    cy.get('[data-test="multidropdown-setting-4"]').find('label').click();
    cy.get('[data-test="multidropdown-setting-4"]').find('label').select(["Option 1"]);
    cy.get('body').click();
    cy.get('[data-test="multidropdown-setting-4"]').find('span').should('have.text', 'Option 1');
   }); // XXX
```

Cypress fails with very strange error without even running the test yet:
[image]

Comment: Maybe because it's multi-select, the menu stays open after a click? Try clicking away from the select, like `cy.get('body').click()` then assert that the menu does not exist.

Comment: To no avail. Updated my post with the test code.

Comment: How to assert the menu does not exist?

Comment: The test looks different to the log, for example can see `.within()` and `.wrap()` in the log

Comment: Ok, that comes from the quasar helper functions. Do you  know which line the test fails at? The helper functions are being invoked and are causing the problem, but I don't know enough about them to say how to adjust the test.

Comment: I think the test fails after the first click judging from the screen capture. I can't tell which line of the test because I don't see any such information from the screen and the stack trace.

Comment: Try commenting out from the bottom up.

Comment: Got it. Second line - `XXX` in my post.

Comment: I resume the quasar helper library overrides the `.select()` command, and is adding something like `cy.wrap('.q-menu').should('not.exist')` which should only be used for a single-select not a multi-select.

Comment: Good explaination. How to select the multi-selection dropdown then?

Answer (score 1):

The Quasar Cypress helpers overrides the `.select()`, see [cypress.overrides.ts](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar-testing/blob/a9e272c00ffdc046cf727cf2d9fb0e56ac33f325/packages/e2e-cypress/src/helpers/commands/cypress-overrides.ts#L32)

```js
if (subject.hasClass('q-select')) {
  if (Array.isArray(valueOrTextOrIndex)) {
    if (!subject.hasClass('q-select--multiple')) {
      throw new Error(
        'Cypress: select command with array param can only be used with a multiple select',
      );
    }
  } else {
    valueOrTextOrIndex = [valueOrTextOrIndex];
  }
```

This shows that the

```html
<q-select
  ...
  multiple
>
```

should throw an error (not the one you get, but the one shown above) when you pass a single value into the `.select()`.

Try passing an array

```js
cy.get('[data-test="multidropdown-setting-4"]')
  .find('label')
  .select(["Option 1"])
```

**BTW** The error message you get above isn't coming from the `.select()` override, but from the `portal` helper. I haven't traced back to that point, but try with the above mod first as it seems most likely.

---

#### Using cy.withinSelectMenu()

This might also work:

```js
cy.get('[data-test="multidropdown-setting-4"]')
  .find('label')
  .click();                      // open the menu

cy.withinSelectMenu(             // should only be one menu open
  {persistent: true},            // this means you have a multiple select
  () => { 
    cy.get('.q-item[role=option]').contains("Option 1").click();
  })
```

Comment: Actually, I think there's a bug that's going to prevent it from working.

Comment: Just tried. Doesn't work. Same error.

Comment: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar-testing/issues/279

Comment: You can work around it by removing the class `.q-select`.

Comment: I don't add this css class anywhere in my code

Comment: It gets added because the template element is `<q-select>`. See the source code at the top of my answer, it that class is not present, the helper just calls original Cypress .select().

Comment: Is there any good substitute for this UI element in quasar?

Comment: It's the class that is removed (inside the test), not the element. You keep the template the same (inside the source code).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I don't use this class in my test code.

Comment: If you look in devtools, you will see it on or near `data-test="multidropdown-setting-4"`. As I mentioned, it gets added to the element because in the template you have used  `<q-select>` element. You can't avoid it - it's just what happens when you set up a q-select. But the test can remove it, in the way I have shown.

Comment: `then($select => $select.removeClass('q-select') ` doesn't work. Error: `cy.select() can only be called on a <select>. Your subject is a: <label class="q-field row no-wrap items-start q-field--borderless q-field--auto-height q-select--without-input q-select--without-chips q-select--multiple q-field--float q-field--labeled full-width" for="f_bf4ac9c0-7988-4a59-b04a-be83111f3830">...</label>`

Comment: `Using cy.withinSelectMenu()` also doesn't work. Error: `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: .q-menu[role=listbox], but never found it.`

Comment: The first one needs brackets, to avoid subject change - I'll update the code.

Comment: The second one needs a command to open the select. I've lost the thread on how that happens, but essentially you need to show the menu (click the dropdown) then use `cy.withinSelectMenu()`.

Comment: First one same error after adding the curly brackets.

Comment: You mean this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73205142/quasar2-vue3-cypress-select-options ?

Comment: How does the second one test specific multi-select control when there are more than one in the web app?

Comment: There should only be one menu open at a time. If you click one open, then click another open, the first should close automatically.

Comment: I think actually your original test code (line 2) attempts to select an option but is actually just opening the select menu. I will add the menu open command above.

Comment: The "Reverting to standard Cypress select() command" didn't work for two reasons - 1) the menu opening and the option selecting are two separate steps, needs two commands. 2) the Cypress select() command can only be used on a native HTML `<select>` but the Quasar select is not actually a select, it's a popup menu.

Comment: BTW you should select "Option 2" since "Option 1" is the initial value. Then the test will confirm that the component actually changes.

Comment: That's your assumption. The model is initialized with an empty array.

Comment: I separate them into 2 steps but have problem validating the UI display as a result of the "selection". Update my post.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Got it to work by going through the quasar testing Github repo. Sample Code if anyone is facing similar issue.

```js
cy.dataCy('select').click()
cy.withinSelectMenu({
      persistent: true,
      fn: () => {
        cy.contains('Option One').click()
      },
    })
```